# How do convert 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to IEnumerable

Tags: wpf

I use this code for select two field

```
     public ViewModelList(CRMEntities crm)
    {
       var cus = (from c in crm.Customer
                  select new 
                  { c.Name, c.Family });
        AllCustomer = new ObservableCollection<Custom>(cus.ToList());
     }
     public ObservableCollection<Custom> AllCustomer
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    }

    public class Custom
   {
     public  string Name{get;set;}
    public string Family { get; set; }

   }
```

, but gives the following error

cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ObservableCollection you are specifying that the element is of type Custom.
When you perform the select you are creating an anonymous type. Using new { ... } will create an anonymous type.

What you probably want to do is

```
select new Custom { Name = c.Name, Family = c.Family };
```